# Usage of moles.runner.exe with MSTest.exe as the test runner

Tags: mstest, moles

When I execute moles.runner.exe, providing MSTest.exe as the runner, I'm seeing an error.

Here is the command line:

```
moles.runner.exe MyAssembly.dll /r:MSTest.exe /args:/resultsfile:output.trx /args:/testcontainer:MyAssembly.dll
```

Here is the output:

```
Microsoft Moles Runner v0.94.51023.0 -- http://research.microsoft.com/moles -- .NET v4.0.30319
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 2007-2010. All rights reserved.

instrumenting...started
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 9.0.30729.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Invalid switch "MyAssembly.dll"
For switch syntax, type "MSTest /help"
```

When I execute moles.runner.exe with /d (Diagnostic mode), it shows this:

```
r>MSTest.exe MyAssembly.dll /resultsfile:output.trx /testcontainer:MyAssembly.dll
```

How can moles.runner.exe be directed to *not* pass the assembly name as the first argument to the test runner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test container should *not* be specified to moles.runner.exe with **/args**, i.e.:

```
/args:/testcontainer:MyAssembly.dll
```

Instead, it should be specified with **/afs** (RunnerAssemblyFormatString) as follows:

```
/afs:"/testcontainer:{0}"
```

That will instruct moles.runner.exe to output the test assembly within the MSTest.exe-required /testcontainer argument.